# Sending CAN-BUS messages from a raspberry pi webserver

Tags: javascript, php, raspberry-pi, webserver, can-bus

We are building a rover which should be controlled via web. It consist in a dozen arduino that split the jobs. One is dedicated to voice commands and text-to-speech, two keeps under control an array of ultrasonic sensors, and so on.

In order to broadcast messages, so other elements can read and use whatever informations they need, we decided to use a can-bus system. The problem is located between the interface and the can-hat of the pi.

Working:
- Pi webserver with php built interface: reacheable and working.
- Pi c-file executable called can_send that receives two parameters (id and message) and drives the can-hat.
- Arduino can reader, a generic arduino that outputs on our PC serial monitor the can messages it receives. It works and by launching can_send on the Pi it gets the correct informations.

Non working:
- From the webserver, without refresh or pages in between, we should click a button and execute the can_send script.

Our initial idea is something like:
PHP interface -> button onclick -> javascript function -> PHP file that executes shell_exec.

We are now struck here. Not knowing if we are digging our graves or a step close to the success.

button on webinterface:

`<button style='width: 100px; height: 100px;background: url(./design/images/right.png)' onclick='cantxedx()'  />`

javascript function (declared at the top of the webpage)

```
function cantxedx() {
    var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    x.open("GET", "../SCRIPTS/can_transmission.php?id=15&msg=001" + document.getElementbyId('myRangeThr'), true);
    x.send();
    return false;
}
     </script>
```

can_transmission.php is the following:

```
     //can_transmission.php

     $TXmsgid= $_GET['id'];
     $TXmsg= $_GET['msg'];

     //formattazione stringa

     $wordsize = sizeof($TXmsg);

     if($wordsize<8)
     {
       while($wordsize<8)
       {
         $TXmsg= $TXmsg . "0";
         $wordsize = sizeof($TXmsg);
       }
     }
     if($wordsize>8)
     {
         //placeholder for building long messages
     }
     $TXstring= "sudo /var/www/html/SCRIPTS/c/can_send ".$TXmsgid." ".$TXmsg;
     $handle = fopen("log.txt", "a+");
           fwrite($handle, $TXstring);
     fclose($handle);

     shell_exec($TXstring);

?>
```

And a slider, which sets the value of the last part of the can-message

```
<div align='center'>
    <p>THROTTLE</p>
</div>
<div class='slidecontainerv'>
    <input type='range' min='5' max='100' step='5' value='50' class='sliderv' id='myRangeThr' orient='vertical' width='500'>
</div>
<div align='center'>
    <p>Value: <span id='throttle'></span>%</p>
</div>
```

The idea is:
when clicking the html button, the desired javascript function is executed.

in this function we call a transmission file, passing the informations we need (id for the message, some informations relative to the button pressed in the first numbers of msg, and another value read from a slider)

The transmission file drives the can-hat, and afterward the message is read and used by the arduino platoon.

Something is not working somewhere between the button and the transmission file. When clicking a button nothing happens, not a new can-bus message nor a new log row.

---

**New informations**

We got something sorted out:
In the HTML button we added

`onclick='cantxebw(\"010\")`

which gives us the ability to reduce javascript function (not one per button).
In the javascript we collected the informations and we got:

```
       function cantxebw(jdir) {

            var jid = '10';

            var slider = document.getElementById('myRangeThr');
            var vt = slider.value;
            var vtx = jid + jdir + vt;
            alert(vtx);
            $.ajax({
                  url: '../SCRIPTS/can_transmission.php',
                  type: 'POST',
                  data: {'id':'jid', 'msg':'vtx'},
                  success: function(data) {
                               console.log(data); // Inspect this in your console
                            }
             });
       };
     </script>  ";
```

At this point, once clicked the button, we have an alert windows with the correct values printed out as we want.
The problems are:
 - the ajax function does not call the php script or does not send values (we tried with a simple form, using the same values and $_POST on can_transmission and it worked).

Even with the form we could not manage to operate via shell exec (via console the script can_send works, but not with shell_exec). Here we tried to see if the path was correct with fileexist and bot with full path or relative path worked.

Comment: Solution found. I will post it as soon as I'm home. Some js and ajax errors, one missing script, and missing permissions (for www-data to run the transmission code.).